# Codility Frog Jumps

Tags: php

I'm working through the codility tests to improve my skills and I don't get a couple issues on this one (https://app.codility.com/programmers/lessons/3-time_complexity/frog_jmp/). I've tried various solutions (see below), but invariably I get this error when I run the test. I don't know what it means, or why I'm getting it. I've run these solutions on my own server and they return the correct value for the test:

```
function solution($X, $Y, $D) {
    $distance = $Y - $X;
    if ( $distance % $D == 0 ) {
        return $distance / $D;
    } else {
        return ( $distance / $D ) + 1; 
    }
}
```

Second solution

```
function solution($X, $Y, $D) {
    $distance = $Y - $X;
    return ceil($distance / $D);
}
```

This is the error I always get:

> Compilation successful.
>   Example test:    (10, 85, 30)  Output (stderr): Invalid result type,
>   int expected (got double) RUNTIME ERROR  (tested program terminated
>   with exit code 1) 
>   Detected some errors.

Comment: Try to cast result to int by `intval`

Comment: Thanks, that worked (for both), and I get why it wold in the first example, because I have a decimal. But why would I need to do that for the second solution, where I am using ceil()? Doesn't that make it an integer?

Comment: From the manual - *ceil ( float $value ) : float*

Comment: Although returned value is integer by meaning, it is still float by type

Comment: Understood. Thanks for the pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Add integer type casting before the returned variable,  check following solution.

```
function solution($x,$y,$d)
{
     $distance = $y-$x;
     if($distance  <= 0)
     {
          return 0;
     }
     $jumps = $distance/ $d ;
     return (int) ceil($jumps);
}
```